# how to import a regular (not library) xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing a part of IOS project,called project1. Instead of changing other part of source code and storyboard to test my code, I want to create a new project, called project2, used to test code. In order to do it, however, I need to import many libraries and source files used by project1. So I want to import project1 as the library of project2, how can I do it?

I just drag project1 into project2, but it didn't work
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider instead of creating a whole different project, to simply create a new target within project 1 that is meant only for testing.  It gets a different appID, info.plist, compilation settings, and anything else you want.

You can most easily start by right-clicking on your current target in the project info view, and selecting "duplicate target".  Then it starts with all of the current settings, libraries and source code files you have in your main project.

That is also the way XCode works when you opt to include unit testing in a new project, so there is a good precedent for the approach.

Comment: If I change codes or storyboard when testing my code, my teammate will be affected even though I use new target, right?

Comment: Only if you check in the changes you are making (if you work with anyone else at all you should use git for version control). A new project is more so you can have other kinds of wrapping code to let you exercise parts of the application without running the application.